# I have to solve this sum but I cannot do it

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I have this sum 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{2^{(k+3)}(k+1)}{(k+3)!}$$
and I have to get the result. 
I have continued like this 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{2^{k}2^3}{k!(k+2)(k+3)} = e^2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{2^3}{(k+2)(k+3)}$$
I don't know if this is a good approach to the problem, but I don not know how to continue, could you help me please? 
Thank you.

Comment: where did you get $e^2$ from?

Comment: @Dan I think the OP thought you could pull out $2^k/k!$ from the summation to get $e^2$... which is not the case.

Comment: @Clarinetist exactly, maybe they can begin by pulling out $2^3$...

Comment: @Clarinetist why can't I pull it out?

Comment: @Irene Your summation is dependent on $k$. Therefore, anything dependent on $k$ in the summation cannot be "factored out" because it is not constant with respect to $k$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Good to know... Then, what can I do?

Comment: @Irene Still thinking about it. It looks like a Binomial Theorem question to me, but that might be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking for $e$-type sums is the right idea. I'd do this:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2^{k+3}(k+1)}{(k+3)!} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2^{k+3}(k+3)}{(k+3)!} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2^{k+3}(-2)}{(k+3)!} \\ &= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{k+2}}{(k+2)!} + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{k+3}}{(k+3)!} \\ &= 2(e^{-2} - 1 - (-2)) + 2(e^{-2} - 1 - (-2) - 2) \\ &= 4e^{-2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great thanks, but why did the $(-1)^k$ dissapeared?

Comment: @Irene I used $(-1)^k = (-1)^{k+2}$ and then $(-1)^{k+2} \cdot 2^{k+2} = (-2)^{k+2}$

Comment: @Irene Notice that $$(-1)^k2^{k+3} = (-1)^{k}2^{k}2^{3} = [(-1)(2)]^{k}2^{3} = (-2)^{k}2^{3} = (-2)^{k}2^{2}2 = (-2)^{k}(-2)^{2}2 = (-2)^{k+2}2$$
because $2^2 = (-2)^2$.

Comment: And what did you do to obtain $2(e^{-2}-1-(-2))...$?

Comment: @Irene In the sum on the left in the second line, replace $k+2$ with $j$. Then the sum becomes $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{(-2)^j}{j!}$. Now this is the sum $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^j}{j!} = e^{-2}$ with the first two terms removed. The first term ($j=0$) is $\frac{1}{0!}=1$, and the second ($j=1$) is $\frac{-2}{1!}=-2$.

Comment: @Irene Notice that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^{k+2}}{(k+2)!} = \sum_{k+2=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^{k+2}}{(k+2)!} = \sum_{k+2=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^{k+2}}{(k+2)!} + \dfrac{(-2)^{0}}{0!} + \dfrac{(-2)^{1}}{1!} -  \dfrac{(-2)^{0}}{0!} - \dfrac{(-2)^{1}}{1!}$$
Now $$\sum_{k+2=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^{k+2}}{(k+2)!} + \dfrac{(-2)^{0}}{0!} + \dfrac{(-2)^{1}}{1!}   = \sum_{k+2=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^{k+2}}{(k+2)!} = e^{-2}$$
and 
$$-\dfrac{(-2)^{0}}{0!} - \dfrac{(-2)^{1}}{1!}=-1-(-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z) = -\left(1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2}\right) + e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k+3}}{(k+3)!} = z^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k+1}}{(k+3)!},
$$ consequently $$z^3 \frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{f(z)}{z^2} \right] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1) z^{k+3}}{(k+3)!}.$$  Evaluating the LHS via a straightforward application of the quotient rule gives $$(z-2) e^z + z+2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1) z^{k+3}}{(k+3)!}.$$  Now letting $z = -2$ gives $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(k+1) 2^{k+3}}{(k+3)!} = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)(-1)^{k+3} 2^{k+3}}{(k+3)!} = 4e^{-2}.$$